# How to retrieve more than 1 annotation to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, powercli

I'm trying to create a report using `Get-annotations` to retrieve some custom values and actually it works fine, but I only can insert 1 value on report on same line, here below is what I do for 1 value only, is there some syntax to use not like this `Get-Annotation -Name value1, value2, value3`

```
$AW= foreach ($vmsowner in $VMsOwners)
{
    $VMlisted = $vmsowner.objectname
    get-vm $VMlisted | Get-Annotation -Name  "Application Owner"| select @{label="VM";expression={$_.AnnotatedEntity}}, @{label="Application Owner";expression={$_.Value}}
}
$AW | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-File  -FilePath $FilenameOwners
```

Comment: What's wrong with `Get-Annotation -Name value1, value2, value3`? Are you having trouble formatting the properties/columns with the correct format when you retrieve multiple annotations?

Comment: If I do like this
`code`
get-vm $VMlisted | Get-Annotation -Name  "Application Owner","Application Name"| select @{label="VM";expression={$_.AnnotatedEntity}}, @{label="Application Owner";expression={$_.Value}}, @{label="Application Name";expression={$_.Value}}


I'll get something like this

vm1    Application Owner Application Owner
vm1    Application Name Application Name
vm2    Application Owner Application Owner
vm2    Application Name Application Name

and I want something like this

vm1    Application Owner Application Name
vm2    Application Owner Application Name

Comment: Thank you a lot @MathiasR.Jessen it worked like a charm !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `Get-Annotation` *inside* the calculated property expression(s):

```
Get-VM |Select @{Name='VM';Expression={$_}},@{Name='Application Owner';Expression={($_ |Get-Annotation -Name 'Application Owner').Value}},,@{Name='Some other tag';Expression={($_ |Get-Annotation -Name 'Some other tag').Value}}
```

It might quickly become unreadable with all those calculated property definitions, but you could generate them from a list of annotation names:

```
# define annotations your want to retrieve per vm
$annotations = 'Application Owner', 'Data Owner', 'Some other tag', 'Something else completely'

# generate calculated property definitions
$properties = @(
    @{Name='VM';Expression={$_}}
    $annotations |ForEach-Object {
        $annotationName = $_
        @{Name=$_;Expression=[scriptblock]::Create("`$(`$_ | Get-Annotation -Name '$_').Value")}
    }
)

# fetch VMs and select properties
Get-VM |Select $properties
```

Comment: If I do option #2 I got this error


Select : The "Name" key has a type, System.Management.Automation.PSObject, that is not valid; expected type is System.String.
At line:1 char:20
+ Get-VM $VMlisted | Select $properties
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DictionaryKeyIllegalValue2,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand

Comment: Did you put something other than just the annotation names in `$annotations`?

Comment: Hi @Mathias

This is what I have 
~~~
# define annotations your want to retrieve per vm $annotations = 'Application Owner', 'Application Name' # generate calculated property definitions $properties = @( @{Name='VM';Expression={$_}} $annotations |ForEach-Object { $annotationName = $_ @{Name=$_;Expression=[scriptblock]::Create("$($_ | Get-Annotation -Name '$_').Value")} } ) # fetch VMs and select properties Get-VM $VMlisted | Select $properties 
~~~